# Modify cell data with CodeIgniter's HTML Table Class

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a good grasp of PHP but decided to try CodeIgniter for a small project I'm working on. With the help of the HTML Table Class I have a mysql table being output as a nice looking html table.

I now need to be able to modify some of the cell contents. I.e an if statement on one cell, if it's a 1 display a link, if it's a 0 don't. In fact, I need to 'do stuff' with most of the fields in this table..mostly to change the values to clickable links which will query certain results.

I'm wondering if this is perhaps not the best use case for this HTML table class. Am I better off just writing my own html for the table in order to manipulate this data more easily. Is the table class just for simple output of data and not much else?

If you could steer me in the right direction that'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the case you need to do the processing and then echo out the respective cell. It's not clear on what you mean by using the HTML table class. Is it for CSS? 
What I do is simply do the processing and echo accordingly using an if statement or something like that. You don't exactly need codeigniter to do this.

```
<table>
<?php
$i = 0;
if($i == 0){
   echo "<tr><td><a href='yourlinkgoeshere'>Link</td></tr>";
} else {
   echo "<tr><td>Just Text</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Or you can even do

```
<table>
  <tr><td>
<?php
$i = 0;
if($i == 0){
   echo "<a href='yourlinkgoeshere'>Link";
} else {
   echo "Just Text";
}
?>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

It would really depend on what you are planning on doing.

-------Answer modified to match codeigniter HTML table class

```
        $this->load->library('table');

        $cars = array
          (
          array("Cars","Stock","Sold"),
          array("Volvo",22,18),
          array("BMW",15,13),
          array("Saab",5,2),
          array("Land Rover",17,15)
          );
        $i = 0;
        while($i < count($cars)){
            if($cars[$i][0] == "BMW"){
                $cars[$i][1] = "Sold Out";
                $cars[$i][2] = "No Stock";
            }
            if($cars[$i][0] == "Land Rover"){
                $cars[$i][1] = "<button class='button'>This Is A Button</button>";
                $cars[$i][2] = "<a href='http://example.com/" . $cars[$i][0] . "'>Click Here</a>";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        echo $this->table->generate($cars);
```

Comment: Are you familiar with CodeIgniter? The HTML Class is as follows https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html. While I'm thankful for your contribution it's just standard PHP which I'm happy enough with - my question is around how this is achieved using CodeIgniter.

Comment: I guess I haven't read the ci documentation then. Ci uses arrays to load data to the table. What u can do is call the model and load the query result to array. Before loading the table data loop through the array to do your checking then add/edit values and then load the array to the class. Would love to give u an example but I'm replying through the app. So might take about an hour to get you an example. But the documentation looks pretty straight forward.

Comment: I have modified the answer